# Cannot edit slides on Libre Impress

Tags: libreoffice

A student of mine is working on a presentation for a report.  The other day, he opened his slideshow and the slides appeared horizontally.  The slides are beside each other instead of on top of each other.  I put it to Normal view and nothing has changed.  While the slides are arranged this way, he cannot edit any of the slides.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Any possibility of a screenshot? You can use http://imgur.com - Is it like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ifr38.png)?

Answer (score 0):

If the slides look like this:

[image: slides]  
You can select and drag the <kbd>Slides</kbd> bar to the left hand side until a dotted line appears on the left side, meaning that it will be dropped there

[image]

If that does not work, you can move or rename the `registrymodifications.xcu` config file in `~/.config/libreoffice/...` to reset the configuration. This may reset other settings as well, which is why I suggested only renaming it. 
You can do this from file manager, either use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and type in:

```
~/.config/libreoffice
```

Or navigate to the home directory, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view hidden files *(beginning with `.`)*, and select `.config` then `libreoffice`, and look for `registrymodifications.xcu`

Hope this helps.